# Copy specified files with condition using gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am trying copy my vendor files to my dev folder using gulp. When I was in development mode, I want copy only the unminified files, if unminified is not present copy minified files. And in production mode I want copy minifed files if files are not present minify the normal files.

my folder structure

```
js
  app.js
jquery
  jquery.min.js
  jquery.js
fontawesome
  fontawesome.min.js
  fontawesome.min.css
  fonts.ttf...
```

Here my basic I had written.

```
var scriptsPath = '../vendor/';
function getFolders(dir) {
    return fs.readdirSync(dir)
        .filter(function(file) {
            return fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory();
        });
}
gulp.task('vendor', function() {
    var folders = getFolders(scriptsPath);
    var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css')
    var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
      var jsFilter;
    if (isProduction) {
        jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.min.js');
    } else {
        jsFilter = $.filter(['**/*.js', '!**/*.min.js']);
    }
        return gulp.src(path.join(scriptsPath, '**/'))
            .pipe(jsFilter)
            .pipe($.if(useSourceMaps, $.sourcemaps.init()))
            .pipe($.if(isProduction, $.uglify({preserveComments: 'some'})))
            .on('error', handleError)
            .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
            .pipe(cssFilter)
            .pipe($.if( isProduction, $.minifyCss() ))
            .on('error', handleError)
            .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
            .on('error', handleError)
            .pipe(gulp.dest(build.vendor.js));
    });
    return es.concat.apply(null, tasks);
});
```

I am trying the last two days using gulp-if& some methods. But not yet get the solution.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to cram way to much into your `vendor` task. The stuff you do with your JS files is completely unrelated to the stuff you do with your CSS files. That's hard to read.

Instead of using `gulp-filter` try splitting `vendor` up into smaller tasks like `vendor-js`, `vendor-css`, etc... and then declare them as dependencies for your `vendor` task:

```
gulp.task('vendor', ['vendor-js', 'vendor-css' /* etc ... */]);
```

Your `vendor-js` task could then look like this:

```
var glob = require('glob');

gulp.task('vendor-js', function () {

  var js = glob.sync('../vendor/**/*.js');

  if (isProduction) {
    // use <file>.min.js, unless there is only <file>.js
    js = js.filter(function(file) {
      return file.match(/\.min\.js$/) ||
        js.indexOf(file.replace(/\.js$/, '.min.js')) < 0;
    });
  } else {
    // use <file>.js, unless there is only <file>.min.js
    js = js.filter(function(file) {
      return !file.match(/\.min\.js$/) ||
        js.indexOf(file.replace(/\.min\.js$/, '.js')) < 0;
    });
  }

  gulp.src(js, { base: '../vendor' })
    .pipe($.if(isProduction,                 // only minify for prod and when
          $.if("!**/*.min.js", uglify())))   // the file isn't minified already
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

Adapting this to you specific needs should be fairly trivial from here on.